# What is the German way of saying "potato, potato"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase-request

The phrase is used in English with different pronunciation (*po-tay-to*, *po-tah-to*), as an example for two different ways of saying the same thing.

Is there a German phrase that can be used in the same way?

Comment: I think the English phrase you want to ask about is *tomayto – tomahto,* as this word is actually features a difference in pronunciation. *Potayto – potahto* is a thing as well, but doesn’t highlight a real phenomenon. Also note that both English phrases are usually used to express something different than pronunciation varieties.

Comment: We recently had "da kommen zwölf auf ein Dutzend". Means the same thing.

Comment: @tofro: *Means the same thing.* – not, if this is about illustrating different pronunciations.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft *potato, potato* is *not* used to illustrate pronunciation, but should rather be understood as "gehopft wie gesprungen".

Comment: @tofro +1 für gehopft.

Comment: @Philipp ...wenn man *bierernst* sein will, kann man auch "gehüpft" sagen ...

Comment: @tofro Ich kenne die Redewendung aus Schwaben. »G'hupft wie g'schbrunge«.

Comment: Bei uns "hopft" man. Das macht der Rest der Deutschen mit Bier. Deshalb war das der Versuch eines Witzes.

Comment: @tofro: potato, potato *is* not *used to illustrate pronunciation* – I know, but this is what he OP assumes, going by his question.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: I doubt that, at least I tend to read "two different ways of saying the same thing" in the wider sense of referring to meaning rather than the pronunciation. Note that the initial mention of pronunciation exclusively explains that the word *potato* is pronounced in two different ways in the phrase "potato, potato".

Comment: @Wrzlprmft like O. R. Mapper suggested, I was referring to a phrase that sounds different when being said, but has the same meaning. The point of it was to illustrate two different views/perceptions on the same topic articulated in a different way, but ending in the same result.

Comment: Side note: "potahto" is not a pronunciation normally used anywhere in the English-speaking world (except in this phrase). It's a reference to a Gershwin song from the 30s: "You like potayto, I like potahto; you like tomayto, I like tomahto; potayto, potahto, tomayto, tomahto, let's call the whole thing off!"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could say „Das ist gehüpft wie gesprungen.“

Comment: As a native German speaker, I never heard this phrase. The answer by Disposable Hero is the correct one.

Comment: @theV0ID to me this a very common phrase.

Comment: @theV0ID Die genannte Phrase ist im ganzen südlichen Sprachraum sehr gängig

Comment: @tofro, im nordöstlichen ebenso.

Comment: I grew up in western Germany (NRW) in the 90s and 0s and am now living in south Germany (Baden-Württemberg). Sorry, never heard it. Maybe it's a matter of age?

Comment: @theVOID Es gibt keine "Sprachkammer" bei irgendeinem Gericht und auch keinen Normenausschuss, der darüber befinden könnte, welche der Dutzenden regionalen Varianten die allein seligmachende sein darf. Pfälzer sagen zum Beispiel   _gehubbst wie gehickelt_, und niemand kann es ihnen verbieten, ihren Dialekt zu gebrauchen. Ich als Ruhrmensch kenn den Spruch als _gehuppt wie gesprungen_, viele sagen hier auch _gehopst wie gesprungen_ oder, seltener, _gehopst wie gedopst_.

Answer (score 9):

I think the most akin thing would be either "Jacke wie Hose" (jacket like pants) or "Das Selbe in grün" (the same thing in green).

Comment: Correction: it should be "dasselbe", not "das selbe". Cannot edit, since my reputation here is apparently too low.

Comment: @theV0ID Das ist nicht ganz richtig. Man kann durchaus "der selbe Mann" schreiben, wenn man eine starke Demonstrativität ausdrücken will. Wenn "der" hier ein Artikel ist, wird es zusammen, wenn es ein Demonstrativpronomen ist, auseinander geschrieben.

Comment: @tofro Das sollte mit einer Quelle belegt werden

Answer (score 2):

Some expressions meaning *doesn't matter*:

> Gehupft/gehüpft/gehopst wie gesprungen
> Jacke wie Hose
> Hans wie Heiri *(Swiss dialect)*
> Gehopft wie gemalzt *(not very frequent, from some beer ad)*

> egal
> einerlei
> (mir) gleichgültig
> mir gleich
> macht keinen Unterschied
> kommt aufs selbe (he)raus
> ist ohne Belang

> wurscht
> schnuppe
> piepegal
> schnurzpiepegal
> piepe
> schnurzpiepe
> scheißegal

> dasselbe in Grün

Comment: [Here](https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/edit/22551) you can find some more expressions giving the same idea. One of the best for me: _Das kannst du halten wie du lustig bist._

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the intended meaning is

> Wat den een'n sin Uhl, is den annern sin Nachtigall
> = Plattdeutsch für: *Was für den einen eine Eule ist, ist für den anderen eine Nachtigall.*

You can express a similar idea by

> Das kann man so und so sehen.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of good answers already, I just want to add one from Saxonian dialect:

> 'rum wie 'num

It is dialact. *'rum* is short for *herum* ("around"). I actually can't say what *num* would be in standard German. The phrase literally translates to "regardless, whether you go around this way or that way".

Comment: Maybe *'num* comes from *hintenum*?

Comment: I was told "hum wie num"

Answer (score -5):

You can say the phrase: "Papperlapapp"

Comment: *Papperlapapp* kenne ich nur, wenn etwas als unsinniges Gerede oder Quatsch abgetan wird.

Comment: Jepp, völlig falsche Antwort für diesen Sachverhalt